# how to skip a line if particular string is a last word in a line?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to skip the line if "book" is the last word.

For Instance,

```
There is a book on the table.
The book is under the table.
Here is a book.
I left my book in the car.
```

Expected result: Line  3 should be skipped

```
There is a book on the table.
The book is under the table.
I left my book in the car.
```

I'm unsure how to write a script to skip that particular line. Any help would be appreciated.

```
with open ("input.txt", "r") as input, open ("output.txt", 'w') as output:
      for line in input:
          if (line.rfind('book')= -1):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.search` here:

```
with open ("input.txt", "r") as input, open ("output.txt", 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
        if (not re.search(r'\bbook\.?\s*$', line)):
            print(line)   # only print lines which DON'T end in 'book'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're ending your lines with a dot. So that must be considered.
You could use re

```
import re #
# in the code for skipping
with open ("input.txt", "r") as input, open ("output.txt", 'w') as output:
    for line in input.readlines():
        if re.findall(r"book\.?$",line): # Ends with book with or without a dot
            continue # omit and continue with next line
        output.write(line)
```

or if you want you could also use a line.endswith("book.\n") in that if